# How do I find the second link occurance using WWW::Mechanize::Firefox and find_link_dom in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I am using find_link_dom and it's working... to find the first link that matches. I need to find the second. Here is my line:

```
my $link = $mech->find_link_dom ( text_regex => 'abc' );
```

Is there a way for this command to return the second link that matches?

And before someone comment that I need to change my search criteria, the text is the same. The only thing different is the url and I don't know just from the url which should be picked. I need the second link that match the above search.

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize doesn't mention a method `find_link_dom`.

Comment: whoops. I forgot the firefox. I'll update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox#mech-find_link_dom-options) says it returns *objects*. That's plural. There is also this piece of code. Note the `for`.

> ```
> print $_->{innerHTML} . "\n"
>     for $mech->find_link_dom( text_contains => 'CPAN' );
> ```

So you can just call it in list context to get all the found links, or just take the one you want.

```
( undef, my $link ) = $mech->find_link_dom ( text_regex => 'abc' );
```

That should give you the second one.

Alternatively, grab all of them and output, to see what's going on.

```
use Data::Printer;

my @links = $mech->find_link_dom ( text_regex => 'abc' );
p @links
```

Or, you can use the option `n`, which is a *1-based index*.

```
my $second_link = $mech->find_link_dom( text_regex => 'abc', n => 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Another question that is somewhat related. Is there a way to search on 'Title' instead of of text?

Comment: @Bill I don't see that there's a built-in way to do that. See https://metacpan.org/source/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#L2317. I guess you'd have to do that with your own XPath expression. If you have trouble with that, ask a new question please.

Comment: @Bill did you find a way to do the `title` thing?

Comment: I didn't. I went a different direction with it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [second method](http://search.cpan.org/~corion/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.78/lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm#$mech-%3Efind_all_links_dom_%25options), from @simbabque documentation reference, that I think you should try:

```
 $mech->find_all_links_dom %options

 print $_->{innerHTML} . "\n"
     for $mech->find_all_links_dom( text_regex => qr/google/i );
```

> Finds all matching linky DOM nodes in the document. The options are documented in ->find_link_dom.
>
> Returns them as list or an array reference, depending on context.
>
> This defaults to not look through child frames.

Comment: Good spot. That's probably the more concise option, though the interface is a bit questionable. But please [edit] your answer and remove the first line. This is fine as an answer, no need to apologize. You can add a working example though.

Comment: Yep, the interface and documentation leave room for improvement.